# Top VS bottom layer conventions

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-layers

Are there any conventions regarding which side of board should be top and which should be bottom? The only convention I can think of is placing the user-facing side on top if the bare board is going to be visible (say, in a shield/hat).

To be clear, I am *not* asking what to put on top or bottom layer. My question is more akin to, "given a complete board, which side would you call top and which bottom, and why?".

Comment: What does this: *if the bare board is going to be visible (say, in a shield/hat)* actually mean?

Comment: @Andyaka The OP is talking about shields for Arduinos and hats for Raspberry Pi. The common name for expansion boards for these popular microprocessors.

Comment: You don't say how many layers your board has. If it's double sided then you probably don't have much choice unless there are relatively few components. On multilayer boards it is common to find power and earth on the two outer layers and the signals mostly in the middle layer(s) but there is no hard and fast rule and your design or application may preclude this. For example you may have to build in transmission lines or keep some components and their signal tracks away from the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a frequent topic in our team and mechanical team. There is no guideline as such. 
**More or less it is truly opinion based**

1. The PCB side which will finally face the user (examples are the PCBs which have buttons or displays facing the user) we call it top layer.
2. If there is no such way to identify, then the side where we have components assembled (one sided PCB assembly) is called top layer.
3. The side where we keep test points for production testing (for the ICT needles) is called bottom layer..but this is just what we follow. It is no standard.
4. If it is a Arduino shield, the PCB facing the top may be called top layer ( my convention)
5. It is truly user dependent.
6. Also, for example, the PCB with no components side can be called bottom layer as in lilypad PCB
7. If it is a bare PCB product, then the side at which it wil be kept visible most of the time can be called top layer
8. The side facing the sky or the user can be called top layer

   [image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is just semantic, but a couple of thoughts:

1. If you have any part(s) that generate significant amounts of heat (e.g. a regulator, large processor) then you would factor in where that hot air will go. As warm air rises, this would usually imply that the these components will be mounted on the top of the board so the air can flow unimpeded.
2. For sanity, when laying out a board in your EDA software, you would imagine that you'd be looking down at the top layer as if the PCB were on your desk. It's therefore intuitive to lay things out like they appear in datasheets, i.e. top down. This saves you thinking about mirroring devices and the pinout issues that will cause.